# MIDI file resets Garritan to default

Tags: midi, musescore

Every time I load a MIDI file into ARIA Player, it resets my mixer board settings once I hit the play button. I am getting the MIDI files from my compositions in Musescore 2. How can I fix this problem?

--Thanks!

Comment: edit the midi file.  which which midi file editor?  that's on you, man.

Comment: presumably your unspecified board is responding to the volume commands intended for the audio channels, or the midi file contains some global resets.

Comment: @StephenHazel What should I do to the file? There was nothing particularly wrong with the file other than the fact that ARIA won't play it using my personal settings.

Answer (score 1):

well, whichever program is sending the midi file's notes and control changes (I'd guess ARIA Player but you don't mention all of your equipment/software), umm whichever midi player you've got shouldn't be sending control changes in the midi file to your mixer board, right?  So figure out

1) why any midi events are being sent to your mixer board

2) either get it to NOT send anything to that device or take out the events in the midi file that are wrecking things...  (by some midi file editor of youuur choice)